# Trying to convert my JSON to a string but get [object Object]

Tags: json, angular, object, asp.net-web-api, webapi

When I try to display my subData in Angular I get **[object Object]**:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TJyDi.png)

I have a model that can contain an array of sites:

```
public class Site
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public string Name { get; set; } = string.Empty;
        public string Url { get; set; } = string.Empty;
        public Site[]? SubData { get; set; }
    }
```

JSON Example:

```
{
    "id": 1,
    "name": "Google",
    "url": "http://www.google.com",
    "subData": [
      {
        "id": 2,
        "name": "Walla",
        "url": "http://www.walla.co.il"
      }
    ]
  },
```

components.ts:

```
export class AppComponent implements OnInit{
  sites: Site[] = [];
  constructor(private siteService:SiteService) { }

  ngOnInit(): void {
    this.GetSites();
  }

  GetSites() {
    this.siteService.GetSites()
    .subscribe((sites) => {
         JSON.stringify(this.sites = sites);
      });
  }
}
```

html:

```
<div *ngFor="let item of sites;">
  <div>Id: {{item.id}}</div>
  <div>Site Name: {{item.name}}</div>
  <div>Site Url: <a href="{{item.url}}">{{item.url}}</a></div>
  <div>{{item.subData}}</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use [json](https://angular.io/api/common/JsonPipe) pipe something like

```
<div>{{item.subData | json}}</div>
```

Update as per comment to display as html element use [ngFor](https://angular.io/api/common/NgFor) loop

```
<div *ngFor="let i of item.subData">
<div> {{i.url}}</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Works for me but if I don't want it to be in a JSON structure because I want to do CSS on it

Comment: you can use it `<pre>{{item.subData | json}}</pre>`

Comment: @DilipHirapara But I don't want the brackets and the array to appear

Comment: @DanielRazal use ngfor to loop on subdata and print the required values.Updated example for url

Answer (score 2):

You make it even cleaner with **async** pipe:

```
<div *ngFor="let item of sites$ | async as site;"> // use async pipe here
  <div>Id: {{site.id}}</div>
  <div>Site Name: {{site.name}}</div>
  <div>Site Url: <a href="{{site.url}}">{{site.url}}</a></div>
  // use ngfor for subdata
  <div *ngFor="let subSite of site?.subData"> // use ? for safety
    <div> {{subSite?.url}}</div>
  </div>
</div>

export class AppComponent implements OnInit{
  sites$: Observable<Site[]>;
  constructor(private siteService:SiteService) { }

  ngOnInit(): void {
    this.GetSites();
  }

  GetSites() {
   this.sites$ = this.siteService.GetSites();
  }
}
```